# How are labels in LDP "Label Mapping Message" associated with IP prefix?

Tags: mpls, ldp

Let's say, that I have two directly connected routers `r1` and `r2`. For example, I do see that the `r2` sends a `Label Mapping Message` to `r1` and provides several labels including `21`(`0x15`):

[image]

`r1` associates the label `21` with prefix `192.0.2.7/32` in the LDP label database:

```
Input label database, 192.0.2.1:0--192.0.2.4:0
Labels received: 7
  Label     Prefix
     23      192.0.2.1/32
     17      192.0.2.2/32
     16      192.0.2.3/32
      3      192.0.2.4/32
     19      192.0.2.5/32
     20      192.0.2.6/32
     21      192.0.2.7/32
```

Why did `r1` associate the label `21` with prefix `192.0.2.7/32`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*FEC Elements* are addresses or prefixes which, when included in an FEC TLV as part of a *Mapping Message*, are mapped to the associated label.

If you expand the *FEC Element 1* section of your packet capture it will most likely display the element `192.0.2.7/32`.  That's encoded in the *FEC TLV* in the format documented in [RFC5036 §3.4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5036#section-3.4.1) and each element has the following structure & fields:

```
Prefix FEC Element value encoding:

       0                   1                   2                   3
       0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 1
      +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
      |  Prefix (2)   |     Address Family            |     PreLen    |
      +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
      |                     Prefix                                    |
      +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+

         Address Family
            Two octet quantity containing a value from ADDRESS FAMILY
            NUMBERS in [ASSIGNED_AF] that encodes the address family for
            the address prefix in the Prefix field.

         PreLen
            One octet unsigned integer containing the length in bits of
            the address prefix that follows.  A length of zero indicates
            a prefix that matches all addresses (the default
            destination); in this case, the Prefix itself is zero
            octets).

         Prefix
            An address prefix encoded according to the Address Family
            field, whose length, in bits, was specified in the PreLen
            field, padded to a byte boundary.
```

The mapping message itself is documented in §3.5.7.